# how to run docker-compose.yaml on kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

My docker-compose file consisting of tomcat7 server and mysql database

```
version: '3'
services:
      mysql:
        image: suji165475/vignesh:latest
        ports:
          - "3066:3066"

      tomcat:
        image: suji165475/vignesh:tomcatserver
        container_name: tomcat7hope
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
```

I built the images using docker files

```
FROM mysql
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
ADD init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

```
FROM picoded/tomcat7
COPY data-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/data-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

how to run this on kubernetes clusture?? I already tried kompose convert and my war file wont start in tomcats application manager.But the war file starts succesfully using docker-compose up.

Why am I facing this issue only in kubernetes and not when directly running docker-compose up.Please help me by letting me know what changes I should make  to the kubernetes yaml files.

mysql-deployment.yaml

```
 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.18.0 (06a2e56)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: mysql
  name: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: suji165475/vignesh:latest
        name: mysql
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3066
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

tomcat-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.18.0 (06a2e56)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: tomcat
  name: tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: suji165475/vignesh:tomcatserver
        name: tomcat7hope
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

mysql-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.18.0 (06a2e56)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: mysql
  name: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "3066"
    port: 3066
    targetPort: 3066
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: mysql
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

tomcat-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert
    kompose.version: 1.18.0 (06a2e56)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: tomcat
  name: tomcat
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8080"
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: tomcat
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Are you able to see what the problem might be in the logs of your containers?

Comment: when I start the warfile in tomcats manager app i get an catalina lifecycle exception

Comment: i think after converting to kubernetes,thr mysql and tomcat containers are not getting linked properly

Comment: but running the docker-compose directly with docker-compose up command starts up the war file without any issues

Answer (score 2):

Let me make it clear, you can't "run docker-compose" on Kubernetes. If you wanted to do that, you should not be using Kubernetes.

With that said, using `kompose` is not such a great idea. Docker compose yaml files are all different and `kompose` simply makes a guess as to what the associated Kubernetes manifests would look like. If your application is very simple and you are lucky, `kompose` might give you your manifests ready to be deployed, but that is not usually the case.

There could be a few reasons why this is not working for you:

- your `tomcat` application is not correctly referencing your `mysql` service
- your `mysql` deployment is missing some variables or mounted volumes/files

Your `tomcat` app can refer to your `mysql` db through `mysql:3066` and you might need to add some environment variables in your `tomcat` deployment such as db name, db username and db password for authentication. Here are your edited `tomcat` manifests:

*deployment.yaml*

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: suji165475/vignesh:tomcatserver
        name: tomcat7hope
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

*service.yaml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tomcat
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: tomcat
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8080"
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: tomcat
```

Your `mysql` deployment might require a `PersistentVolumeClaim` or `emptyDir` in order to keep your data. Take a look at attached volumes and confirm that you are not missing any volume mounts or environment variables that are needed. Here are your edited `mysql` manifests:

*deployment.yaml*

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: suji165475/vignesh:latest
        name: mysql
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3066
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: root
```

*service.yaml*

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "3066"
    port: 3066
    targetPort: 3066
  selector:
    app: mysql
```

Comment: hi since i am doing this on a server using the putty terminal do i have to specify spec type NodePort instead of port 8080??

Comment: and do I have to do the same for the mysql service also??

Comment: @SwethaSwaminathan No, you don't want to expose MySQL for the outside world. And for the communication with MySQL service, you can always communicate with qualified DNS name like `mysql.default.svc.cluster.local` with your Cluster.

Comment: NodePort is used to open a specific port in all VMs, so you can get external traffic directly in your service. Here `port: 8080` is for service to listen on and proxy traffic to available pods. Here what happens is `NodePort -> ServicePort -> Pod`

Comment: hi i have recently changed my code and have posted my question again here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56059061/unable-to-connect-tomcat-container-to-mysql-database-container-in-kubernetes?noredirect=1#comment98758780_56059061